# How can you withdraw an unlocked wallet that is holding 74%34 lp

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

If an unlocked wallet is holding 74.34% of LP and recommended that it should be with pinklock which I did but didn't work out so they any other way to swap back ur coin to BNB